# Android Spinner setSelection calls onItemSelected immidiately or not?

Tags: android

I have 2 spinners in an activity.

Based on the selection of one item in `spinner1`, relevant data should be loaded in `spinner2`. Consider `spinner1` has data related to country and `spinner2` has data related to state.

I should be able to get this done once the activity is created and if the user changes the selection in `spinner1`.

But I am stuck with populating the `spinner2` data based on the saved value of `spinner1`.

I am calling `spinner1.setSelection(indexSaved)` but since I am only loading `spinner2` in the `onItemSelectedOf` of `spinner1`, `setSelection` of `spinner1` is not firing the `onItemSelected`.

Please let me know how I can achieve this.

Comment: add your code what you did till now?

Answer (score 0):

I have done same thing in my project without any problem:
 Below is code may be it help you:

On Create Method filled state list:

//initialize spinners

```
spinnerStateList = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerStateList);    
spinnerDistrictsList = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerDistrictsList);
fillStateList();

public void fillStateList()
{

    states = manage_states.fetchAllStates(getApplicationContext()); 
    //add new element for select name
    states.add(0,new RowItem("-1", "Select State"));
    String[] spinnerArray = new String[states.size()];
    for(int i= 0;i<states.size();i++)
    {
        spinnerArray[i] = states.get(i).getName();
    }
    ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,spinnerArray);    
    dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinnerStateList.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
    spinnerStateList.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0,
                View arg1, int position, long arg3) {               
            String selectedStateID = states.get(position).getId();  
            fillDistrictsSelectionChangeState(selectedStateID);
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {


        }
    });
}

public void fillDistrictsSelectionChangeState(String selectedStateID)
    {
        if(selectedStateID.equalsIgnoreCase("-1"))
        {
            linearLayoutDistrictsList.setVisibility(LinearLayout.GONE);
            linearLayoutBlocksList.setVisibility(LinearLayout.GONE);
            linearLayoutPHCList.setVisibility(LinearLayout.GONE);
            linearLayoutSHCList.setVisibility(LinearLayout.GONE);
    }
    else
    {

        linearLayoutDistrictsList.setVisibility(LinearLayout.VISIBLE);   
        districts = manage_districts.fetchAllDistrictsByStateId(getApplicationContext(), selectedStateID);  
        //add new element for select name
        districts.add(0,new RowItem("-1", "Select District"));
        String[] spinnerArray = new String[districts.size()];
        for(int i= 0;i<districts.size();i++)
        {
            spinnerArray[i] = districts.get(i).getName();
        }
        ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,spinnerArray);
        dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinnerDistrictsList.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
        spinnerDistrictsList.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0,
                    View arg1, int position, long arg3) {               
                String selectedDistrictID = districts.get(position).getId();    
                fillBlocksSelectionChangeDistrict(selectedDistrictID);
            }


            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {


            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: You can initialize both spinners on onCreate and make states spinner visibility gone until user select country drop down.

Comment: Thanks Rahul for the code posted. I have no problem in setting up default spinners. I have only problem if I need to poppulate the previously saved data. Say I have selected Country as india earlier, when I open up the activity The country spinner is set to India as I will use setSelection with the position of india for country spinner. But If I had selected state as Karnataka earlier , I am not able to set it when the country is set . The state adapter is null initially, as I too had the code for setting up the state in onItemSelected call back of the country spinner!

Comment: In that case if you set selection of country dropdown in code its by default called ItemSlelectedListner if you set "true" for animate in setSelection. For example :        spinnerLogging.setSelection(adapterSpinnerLogging.getPosition(hashMap.get(settings.log_enabled)),true); It called the listner when you set item on page load and there you can load here your state spinner.